# How to read Syntax of Error Log in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, syntax-error

I have the following error log:

```
2023/11/28 15:37:26 [error] 106#106: *44 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while
connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: DOMAIN.com, request: "GET
/PATH/TO/FILE HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3000/PATH/TO/FILE", host:
"www.DOMAIN.com"
```

Everything looks plausible but what is the meaning of `106#106: *44`? 
Particularly about the format `X#Y: *Z`. Is it `PORT_NUMBER#PORT_NUMBER: PROTOCOL_NUMBER`?

I've googled and searched for error syntax but couldn't find anything relating to this.

Comment: Are you getting this message from the payload message? Maybe the reason behind the formatting is explained by the resource or product originating these messages, and not Cloud Logging. Could you share the complete log?

Comment: Yes it is from the payload message. The resource this log came from is a kubernetes cluster. But I couldn't find anything about it either... @AndreuElLios

Comment: Hello! Searching this message error brought me to one [guide](https://betterstack.com/community/guides/logging/how-to-view-and-configure-nginx-access-and-error-logs/) related to Nginx Access. Are you running nginx? Are these access logs? You can also create custom log formats following this [guide](https://betterstack.com/community/guides/logging/how-to-view-and-configure-nginx-access-and-error-logs/#step-4-creating-a-custom-log-format) if that's the case.